# Updating / refreshing the mini-TOC inside of a Framemaker document (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, framemaker

I'm currently trying to automate a process using Framemaker's built-in scripting editor. This process involves refreshing the mini-TOC, but I can't find a method for doing that.

The only thing I found out is that the mini-TOC is an Inline Component (see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/framemaker/2017/scripting/framemaker_scripting.pdf 5.53), but that does not give me anything I can work with.

I can't offer any code of what I have besides

```
var doc = app.ActiveDoc;
```

There is only one mini-TOC inside of my document. If there is no way to refresh / update the mini-TOC: Can you give me a way to delete it and create a new one?

The reason I want to update the mini-TOC is that I switch conditions and need a pdf with the correct mini-TOC for each condition.

I'm using Framemaker 2015 on Windows 7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Can you give me a way to delete it and create a new one?_ : `window.location.reload` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate how to do that, @MarcosPérezGude?